# When is "session" argument necessary in R shiny server function?

Tags: r, server, shiny

I am very new to Shiny and I have gone through all the tutorials on the Rstudio website, and have run and tested example apps myself.

I noticed that in Joe Cheng's reactivity videos he always puts `session` as an argument in the server function like this:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {}
```

while in most of the other examples I see

```
server <- function(input, output) {}
```

I know that the session argument is optional, but I wonder whether there is a situation where it is absolutely needed. What is the difference with or without the session argument?

I could not find an explanation anywhere else.

Comment: If you use any ‵shiny::update*‵ functions that require you to pass it to them, then you need it. Otherwise, you probably don't.